# How to check if ftp is installed in a linux server

Tags: linux, ftp

I just want to know if a FTP server is installed on my server. It is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga). I tried running the below command and got connection refused :

```
$ ftp localhost
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: can you be more specific regarding your linux distribution ?

Comment: Which distribution of linux?

Comment: its Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 9):

If you know the package name you could do something like

```
dpkg -l vsftpd
```

to see what the package is about.

If you don't have any idea about package name

On debian or debian based systems you may do

```
dpkg -l | grep ftp # grab everthing that contain ftp
```

And with the results, you may do

```
dpkg -p result
```

On Redhat or Redhat based systems like Fedora , you may do

```
rpm -qa | grep ftp
```

and with the results

```
rpm -qi result # to know more about the package, whether it is the server itself or some suplimentary
```

On Systems like Fedora

```
yum list installed | grep ftp
```

Then do

```
yum info package_name
```

Comment: Why use `--get-selections`, `-l` is a lot simpler and just as good in this case.

Comment: @Henrik : Updated and thanks for the info. I recently migrated from Redhat to Debian and am getting used to it

Comment: and no need for grep with `dpkg` either - `dpkg -l '*ftp*'` works just fine (the single quotes are to avoid shell globbing in case there are files or sub-directories that match `*ftp*` in the current directory).

Answer (score 3):

`ftp` is installed, otherwise you would get some "command not found error" what is not installed, or not configured is the FTP server (probably `ftpd`)

Answer (score 2):

If You are a RHEL user you can use:

```
service vsftpd status
```

It will give the following response if the service *is not* running :

```
vsftpd: unrecognized service
```

and if the service *is* running in your server:

```
vsftpd (pid XXXX) is running...
```

You are getting `ftp: connect: Connection refused` because you have the FTP client installed in the system but FTP server is not installed. You can install the FTP server `vsftpd` and try the same it should work.